# Check in PGSQL if two ids match in two ways

Tags: postgresql, matching

I have two Users ids : ID_User1 and ID_User2. I would like to check in my TABLE if there is duplicate entry for ID_User1 match with ID_User2 and ID_User2 match with ID_User 1 like this :

1 match with 2
1 match with 2

but also

2 match with 1

I actually do this :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2") AS COUNT FROM "WU_MatchingUsers") tableWithCount WHERE tableWithCount.count > 1;
```

and here is the result :

```
id | IDWU_User1 | IDWU_User2 | MatchingScore | count 
----+------------+------------+---------------+-------
  1 |          1 |          2 |            39 |     2
 46 |          1 |          2 |            35 |     2
  2 |          1 |          3 |            41 |     2
 47 |          1 |          3 |            35 |     2
```

But I would like this results :

```
id | IDWU_User1 | IDWU_User2 | MatchingScore | count 
----+------------+------------+---------------+-------
  1 |          1 |          2 |            39 |     3
 46 |          1 |          2 |            35 |     3

 48 |          2 |          1 |            35 |     3

  2 |          1 |          3 |            41 |     2
 47 |          1 |          3 |            35 |     2
```

I want to also have the row in middle. So also check if there is a duplicate row / a matching in the way B > A and not only A > B.

Kind regards !

Answer (score 0):

Make it a case expression wether id1 greater id2.
I used primes to combine the ids uniquely, string-concatenation with delimiter would do, too:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN IDWU_User1 > IDWU_User2 THEN IDWU_User1*2 + IDWU_User2*3 ELSE IDWU_User1*3 + IDWU_User2*2 END ) 
AS COUNT FROM WU_MatchingUsers) tableWithCount WHERE tableWithCount.count > 1
```

**RESULT**

[image]

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a5b28f3baa64330a2e2335d958c4a77)